# AvalonDock focus LayoutDocument content

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

When a `LayoutDocument` is created and shown on screen, it gets the focus. I want to be able to put the focus on my content inside this document.

How can I set the focus of my content inside the document after the document is shown?

I have tried a few things like `ILayoutUpdateStrategy.AfterInsertDocument`, but the document isn't on the screen at this time. I can't find a hook that happens after the document is actually shown on screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you were able to find an answer to this but what I did was in my XAML I added this. `Loaded="Window_Loaded"` and then in my code behind it will set focus to my text box.

Comment: That totally worked. I swear I tried everything, but apparently missed doing on the UserControl directly.